# change dropdown from array to check box

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I would like a change from the drop down to the checkbox, I want to change it because I want firstly select the list in the array can be selected before store to database via the checkbox, so the dropdown script was as follows

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DEFAULT_SOURCE','Site_A'); 
define('DEFAULT_VALUE',100);
define('DEFAULT_STC','BGS');
include('class/stockconvert_class.php');
$st = new st_exchange_conv(DEFAULT_SOURCE);
if(isset($_GET['reset'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['selected']);
    header("Location: ".basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    exit();
}
?>
<form action="do.php" method="post">
<label for="amount">Amount:</label>
<input type="input" name="amount" id="amount" value="1">
<select name="from">
<?php
$stocks = $st->stocks();
asort($stocks);
foreach($stocks as $key=>$stock)
{
    if((isset($_SESSION['selected']) && strcmp($_SESSION['selected'],$key) == 0) || (!isset($_SESSION['selected']) && strcmp(DEFAULT_STC,$key) == 0))
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $stock; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $stock; ?></option>
    <?php   
    }
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Convert">
</form>
```

and i Changed it to the checkbox as follows

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DEFAULT_SOURCE','Site_A'); 
define('DEFAULT_VALUE',100);
define('DEFAULT_STC','BGS');
include('class/stockconvert_class.php');
$st = new st_exchange_conv(DEFAULT_SOURCE);
if(isset($_GET['reset'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['selected']);
    header("Location: ".basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
    exit();
}
?>
<form action="do.php" method="post">
<label for="amount">Amount:</label>
<input type="input" name="amount" id="amount" value="1"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Convert">
<?php
$stocks = $st->stocks();
asort($stocks);
foreach($stocks as $key=>$stock)
{
    if((isset($_SESSION['selected']) && strcmp($_SESSION['selected'],$key) == 0) || (!isset($_SESSION['selected']) && strcmp(DEFAULT_STC,$key) == 0))
    {
    ?>
    <br><input type="checkbox" id="scb1" name="from[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" checked="checked"><?php echo $stock; ?>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <br><input type="checkbox" id="scb1" name="from[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $stock; ?>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
</form>
```

but does not work, am I need to display Other codes related?

Thanks if some one help, and appreciated it

**UPDATED:**
ok post the first apparently less obvious, so I will add the problem of error

the error is
Fatal error: Call to undefined method st_exchange_conv::convert() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\do.php on line 21

line 21 is `$st->convert($from,$key,$date);`

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include('class/stockconvert_class.php');
    $st = new st_exchange_conv(DEFAULT_SOURCE);
    $from = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['from']));
    $value = floatval($_POST['amount']);
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $_SESSION['selected'] = $from;
    $stocks = $st->stocks();
    asort($stocks);

    foreach($stocks as $key=>$stock)
    {
        $st->convert($from,$key,$date);
        $stc_price = $st->price($value);
        $stock = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($stock));
        $count = "SELECT * FROM oc_stock WHERE stock = '$key'";
        $result = mysql_query($count) or die(mysql_error());
        $sql = '';
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE oc_stock SET stock_title = '$stock', stc_val = '$stc_price', date_updated = '$date' WHERE stock = '$key'";
        }
        else
        {       
        $sql = "INSERT INTO oc_stock(stock_id,stock_title,stock,decimal_place,stc_val,date_updated) VALUES ('','$stock','$key','2',$stc_price,'$date')";
        }   
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error().'<br />'.$sql);
    }
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Why I want to change it from dropdown to checkbox?
because with via checkbox list I will be able to choose which ones I checked it was the entrance to the database, then it seem not simple to me, I looking for some help< thanks So much For You mate.

Comment: Please specify "does not work"! Is there an error in the php code? Or is the HTML output not correct/valid?

Comment: OK, now i already updated, please have a look, thanks Simon

Comment: Your new error means it cannot find the convert method ....  Is that defined in your class?

Comment: Hi CarpeNoctumDC, sorry if i can understand correctly, the st_exchange_conv::convert() already defined in the class, using dropdown all data/list stored to database work fine, then i try to changed it to checkbox list that mean i want to filter which ones I checked it was the entrance to the database. but I am need to learn how to do it from someone, Thanks for your kind and help.

Answer (score 0):

You have not removed the opening `<select>` tag.

But you removed the `<submit>` button.

You changed the `name` from "from" to "from[]".

*EDIT:* After your additions:

Using the dropdown list you were only able to select one value for `from`. Now you changed it to checkboxes and thus are able to select multiple entries. This results in receiving an array `from[]` in your script in `do.php`. Your functions there are not able to handle arrays or multiple selections in any way.

You have to re-design `do.php`, change your form back to a dropdown list or use ratio buttons instead.

Comment: even though I have it back name from "from[]" to "from". but still error, but I appreciate your help, thanks again

Comment: I appreciated your time for this Simon, I did update for the second time, hopefully You have any idea after completely read what i looking for, thanks again.

Comment: It is like I said: your function `convert()` can not handle arrays as input for parameter `$from`. I can not really see why you want to use checkboxes and not ratio buttons?!

Comment: Hi Simon, I'm not using dropdown anymore because it will store all data on array listed, but I want store data to database from array listed base on checked it from checkbox, does use radio buttons can fix it? thanks